# Matlab GUI:Setting Current Axes creates a new figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have created a GUI with 3 axes: `axes1`, `axes2`, `axes3`. I have a class `SP` to whose constructor I pass the three axes as follows:

```
a=SP(handles.axes1,handles.axes2,handles.axes3)
```

The class looks something like

```
class SP < handles
   properties
      axes1
      axes2
      axes3
   end
   methods
      function A=SP(axes1,axes2,axes3)
          A.axes1=axes1;
          A.axes2=axes2;
          A.axes3=axes3;
          axes(A.axes1);
          rectangle('Position',[randn,randn,randn,randn]);
          axes(A.axes2);
          rectangle('Position',[randn,randn,randn,randn]);
          axes(A.axes3);
          rectangle('Position',[randn,randn,randn,randn]);
      end
```

I have written a timer function

```
function timerfcn1(~,~,A)
    axes(A.axes1);
    rectangle('Position',[randn,randn,randn,randn]);
    axes(A.axes2);
    rectangle('Position',[randn,randn,randn,randn]);
    axes(A.axes3);
    rectangle('Position',[randn,randn,randn,randn]);
end
```

My problem is that during the initialization i.e when i call the constructor, the rectangles are plotted in the GUI window. However, whenever the `timerfcn1` runs it creates a new figure and plots the rectangle in that.

I had used a similar thing before and it used to work then.

Comment: I cannot run this code!! please modify the code so that we could be able to run

Comment: edited the code. But how do i show the gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's related to handle visibility (or lack of) in a part of the code that you haven't shown.  To guarantee that the rectangle goes to the axis you want use,

```
rectangle('Position',[...],'Parent',A.axes1)
```

Before this you should also check that the handle still exists using

```
if ishandle(A.axes1)
...
end
```